# How do I extract messages from multiple specific folders with FormatJS CLI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-intl

I have `/components/foo.js` and `/pages/bar.js`, both are using `<FormattedMessage />` with a different `defaultMessage`:

```
// /components/foo.js
export default function Foo() {
  return (
    <FormattedMessage defaultMessage="Foo component" />
  );
}

// /pages/bar.js
export default function Foo() {
  return (
    <FormattedMessage defaultMessage="Bar page" />
  );
}
```

If I run `formatjs extract 'components/**/*.js' --out-file lang/en.json` I only get messages from my components folder. If instead I use the path `pages/**/*.js`, I only get messages from my pages folder.

Tried a few differente combinations without luck:

- `(components,pages)/**/*.js`
- `(components&pages)/**/*.js`
- `(components|pages)/**/*.js`
- `!(node_modules)/**/*.js` to compile everything except the `node_modules` folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that you need to use double pipe operator `||`.

```
formatjs extract '(components||pages)/**/*.js' --out-file lang/en.json
```

Answer (score 1):

We use https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob so `{components,pages}/**/*.js` should work

Answer (score 1):

Tried all the solutions mentioned above but what actually worked for us was formatjs extract 'components/**/*.js' 'pages/**/*.js' --out-file lang/en.json